# Undefined reference to enum

Tags: c++, polymorphism

I'm getting this error message from my compiler:

```
undefined reference to `Pawn::Pawn(Piece::Color)'
```

This occurs when I do this:

```
// board[][] contains pointers to Piece objects
board[0][0] = new Pawn(Piece::BLACK);
```

Here's part of the Pawn class:

```
// Includes...
#include "piece.h"
// Includes...

class Pawn : public Piece {
public:
        // ...

        // Creates a black or white pawn.
        Pawn(Color color);

        // ...
};
```

Here's part of the Piece class:

```
class Piece {
public:
        // ...

        enum Color {WHITE, BLACK};

        // ...
};
```

Why am I getting this compiler error?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The error doesn't really have anything to do with the enum. You need to define the Pawn(Color) constructor, e.g.,

```
Pawn::Pawn(Color)
{
...
}
```

Comment: Wow... I can't believe I completely forgot to write the constructor. I think I'll need to try that coffee thing I've heard so much about.

Answer (score 5):

You need to define a function body for the constructor.

This code gives the linker error: http://www.ideone.com/pGOkn

```
    Pawn(Color color) ;
```

This code will not:  http://www.ideone.com/EkgMS

```
    Pawn(Color color) {}
    //                ^^ define the constructor to do nothing.
```

Answer (score 4):

The problem isn't with the enum, it's that the linker can't find the implementation of `Pawn::Pawn(Color)`. Have you implemented the `Pawn::Pawn(Color)` constructor and is it being linked here?